# SQL Select x from a set of value

Tags: sql

Hi guys i have a problem about how to select value from a set of value in SQL and my code look like this:

```
Select distinct subreddit from reddit
where author = (select distinct author from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2');
```

Code in the () return more than one author but when i run this query it only gets the value of one author. What should i do to get value from all the authors () part returns?

Comment: you are lucky that the sql doesn't give you an error. if you use a select subquery you have to use in instead of = as more than 1 return value gives you an error in most cases.   Can it be that link_id = 'xxxxx' only is true for 1 single author?

Comment: no, it return more than one actually, and i don't know why i didn't get a error...

Comment: That is interesting. what database type do you use? (I'm intrigued there which database now accepts that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you simply want `IN` instead:

```
Select distinct subreddit from reddit
where author IN (select author from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2');
```

**Note**: No need for `distinct` in the sub-query.

Comment: Or use WHERE EXISTS(SELECT author from redidit...)

Comment: One thing that intrigues me though is that the OP does not get an error = with multiple entries should result in an error (at least in older versions of mysql and sql server). can it be that he in reality just gets 1 value? (or did it change since the past times so that getting multiple results from teh subselect does not result in an error)?

Comment: @Thomas, I know, I noticed that too. This query is better anyway.

Comment: @jarlh the OP has answered it already in a comment in teh main question. I'm surprised that the database didn't bring an error there (will be interesting which engine it is as that comes as a surprise). And yepp your query is more functional and better than the OPs (also no distinct needed!)

Answer (score 1):

Use

`Select distinct T.subreddit from reddit T
 where EXISTS
        (select author from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2'and author = T.author);`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to using EXIST instead of IN statement.

The IN statement will execute the full query inside the IN-statement. In the below example the (select author from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2') will be executed and then compared to the value in author

```
Select subreddit from reddit
where author IN (select author from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2');
```

If you use EXISTS instead:

```
Select subreddit from reddit t
where EXISTS(select rownum from reddit where link_id = 't3_j56j2' and author = t.author);
```

The query in exist will stop executing at the first match and will be the better option for performance.